# Calculating Conditional Probability for the following case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following :

1. $S$ is a Gaussian Random Variable whose mean is $0$ and variance is $\sigma_S^2$.
2. $V_i$ s are independent Gaussian Random Variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$ where $1\leq i\leq L$. $V_i$s are are also independent of $S$.
3. $N_i$ s are independent Gaussian Random Variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_{n{_i}}^2$ where $1\leq i\leq L$. $N_i$s are are also independent of $S$ and $V_i$.
4. $H_i$ s are independent exponential Random Variables with unit mean where $1\leq i\leq L$. $H_i$s are  independent of $S$ and $V_i$ and $N_i$.

The random variables are related by the following equations:

1. $X_i=S+V_i$
2. $Y_i=\sqrt{H_iw_i}X_i+N_i$. Here $w_i$s are multiplying factors which are assumed to be constants for $1\leq i\leq L$.

I know that $Y_i\ \text{and}\ S$ are pairwise jointly Gaussian,where $1\leq i\leq L$ .This can be proved using $P[Y_i,S]=P[Y_i|S]P[S]$.
I am trying to find out the joint distribution of $Y_i\ \text{and}\ S$ conditioned on $H_i \geq \theta_i$ where $1\leq i\leq L$. $\theta_i$s are constants. I have tried  2 approaches.They are as follows:

$\mathbf{Approach\ 1}$:

$P[Y_i \leq y_i,S \leq s|H_i \geq \theta_i$,$1\leq i\leq L$]$=P[Y_i \leq y_i| S \leq s,H_i \geq \theta_i]\times P[S \leq s | H_i \geq \theta_i$].

So we have,
$P[Y_i \leq y_i,S \leq s|H_i \geq \theta_i$,$1\leq i\leq L]$= $P[\sqrt{\theta_iw_i}S+\sqrt{\theta_iw_i}V_i+N_i \leq y_i| S \leq s]\times P[S \leq s ]$.

I am stuck in the last expression.

$\mathbf{Approach\ 2}$:

$P[Y_i = y_i,S = s|H_i \geq \theta_i$,$1\leq i\leq L$]$=P[Y_i = y_i| S = s,H_i \geq \theta_i]\times P[S = s | H_i \geq \theta_i$],

or, $P[Y_i = y_i,S = s|H_i \geq \theta_i,1\leq i\leq L]=P[\sqrt{\theta_iw_i}S+\sqrt{\theta_iw_i}V_i+N_i \leq y_i| S = s]\times P[S = s ]$,

Now,since $N_i\ \text{and} \ V_i$ are independent Gaussians, their linear combination will also be Gaussian.We denote the resultant Random Variable by $N_{ri}$ with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma{_{ri}}^2$.So we have,

$P[Y_i = y_i,S = s|H_i \geq \theta_i,1\leq i\leq L]=P[N_{ri} \leq y_i-\sqrt{\theta_iw_i}S| S = s]\times P[S = s ]$.

Using the fact that $N_i$ and $V_i$ are are independent of $S$,

$P[Y_i = y_i,S = s|H_i \geq \theta_i,1\leq i\leq L]=P[N_{ri} \leq y_i-\sqrt{\theta_iw_i}s]\times P[S = s ]$.

or,

$P[Y_i = y_i,S = s|H_i \geq \theta_i,1\leq i\leq L]=\Phi (\frac{y_i-\sqrt(\theta_iw_i)s}{\sigma_{ri}}) \times P[S = s ]$, where $\Phi(x)$ denotes the cdf of standard Normal variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

I am not sure whether any of the approaches are going in the right direction. Another thing, I have tried integrating approach 2 over the limits $-\infty \ \text{to} +\infty$ for both the random variables but the result is not converging.

It will be very helpful, if someone can pint me in the right direction. I apologize for any mistake in my post.